# Confusion with Photoshop UI boolean syntax

Tags: javascript, boolean, ecmascript-5, photoshop-script

I can create a simple Photoshop UI with

```
var dlg = new Window("dialog"); 

// add buttons
dlg.add ("button", undefined, "OK");
dlg.add ("button", undefined, "Cancel");

// show the dialog;
dlg.center();

var myReturn = dlg.show();

if (myReturn == true)
{
   var msg = myReturn;
   alert(msg);
}
```

My question is this: Why is

`if (myReturn == true || myReturn == 1) { do something }' // okay button works fine`

not the same as

`if (myReturn) { do something } // doesn't work (all buttons work, including cancel)`

Ordinarily, `if(bool)` is the same as `if (bool == true)`
Is this a Photoshop qwerk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Window.show()` returns an integer, not a boolean. There are several key words like `Ok` and `Cancel` that Photoshop knows and buttons with these words return hardcoded values (`1` for `Ok` and `2` for `Cancel`). You can set custom returns in `.onClick()`:

```js
var dlg = new Window("dialog"); 

// add buttons
dlg.add ("button", undefined, "OK");
var al = dlg.add ("button", undefined, "Close with custom return value");
dlg.add ("button", undefined, "Cancel");

al.onClick = function () {
  dlg.close(10)
}

// show the dialog;
dlg.center();

var myReturn = dlg.show();

// Ok will alert 1
// Close with custom return value will alert 10
// Cancel will alert 2
alert(myReturn);
```

Comment: Dat make a lot more sense now!